# How to set max_connections in MySQL Programmatically

Tags: mysql, database

I have a server where a lot of users will connect to it and use a database there, and I am using MySQL. I know that the default number of `max_connections` in MySQL is 100 or 150 but I am sure I need way beyond that number, therefore I used the following to increase the number:

```
SET global max_connections = 1000000
```

Now I try to check the `max_connections` as follows:

```
show variables like 'max_connections'
```

It gives me the following:

```
max_connections; 100000;
```

Which is a sign that it succeeded (unless I am understanding it wrong). When my users start to connect I am receiving an error from the server when the number of connected users exceeds 110. The error is:

> error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior
>   to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred
>   because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was
>   reached.

Why am I getting this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can change max_connections programmatically because changing that max requires a server restart. Maybe you could, but probably shouldn't...?

Comment: Hmm, you mean I should do the start-up setup of MySQL and select the settings from there?

Comment: You need to restart the server in order for the new max to take effect outside the context of your own connection. Thus, you specify the max var in the settings file.

Comment: I will try it and inform you what happens, thanks.

Comment: Note that max_connections is at default to 200 for a reason, and setting 1.000.000 is probably nonsense for your hardware resources. Also, probably the problem is not related to this fix. Try inspecting your `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to understand what is happening and if there are really few connections available or if it's something else. Please add these info in your question.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

## How to change `max_connections`

You can change `max_connections` while MySQL is running via `SET`:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections = 5000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 5000  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## To OP

### `timeout` related

I had never seen your error message before, so I googled. probably, you are using Connector/Net. [**Connector/Net Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) says there is max connection pool size. (default is 100) see table 22.21.

I suggest that you increase this value to 100k or disable connection pooling `Pooling=false`

### UPDATED

he has two questions.

**Q1 - what happens if I disable pooling**
Slow down making DB connection. `connection pooling` is a mechanism that use already made DB connection. cost of Making new connection is high. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

**Q2 - Can the value of pooling be increased or the maximum is 100?**

you can increase but I'm sure what is MAX value, maybe `max_connections` in my.cnf

My suggestion is that do not turn off Pooling, increase value by 100 until there is no connection error.

If you have Stress Test tool like `JMeter` you can test youself.

Comment: Thanks Jungsu, my problem is in pooling not in max_connections. I have 2 small questions here: what happens if I disable pooling, can I still support multiple connections? Can the value of pooling be increased or the maximum is 100? I understood from the link you provided that its maximum is 100, am I right?

Comment: @antf I have updated my answer. are you still getting a connection error?

Comment: When I run `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 5000;` inside PhpMyAdmin I get: "Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation". In other words: You need to SSH into your server and then execute `mysql` and afterwards `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 5000;`

Answer (score 2):

For Windows,

1. Go to c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.init
2. Add `max_connections = <your value>`
   example   `max_connections = 5000`

For Ubunutu:

1. Go to `sudo /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf/`
2. Add `max_connections = your value`
   example   `max_connections = 5000`
3. `sudo systemctl reload-deamon`

Answer (score 1):

You can set max connections using:

`set global max_connections = '1 < your number > 100000';`

This will set your number of mysql connection unti (Requires `SUPER` privileges).