# User Login Authentication Failure - WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: mysql, jdbc, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We're having users created under *Secondary Userstore(JDBC Userstore)*. Similarly, we have an application called `MyApplication` created in API Store. When users are trying to login to that `MyApplication` by invoking `/token` API which was provided by WSO2 even with correct username (in the format of *TESTDOMAIN/testuser*) and password also. Sometimes login is getting failed by returning a response with `400 Bad Request`:

```
 {
        "error_description": "Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION",
        "error": "invalid_grant"
 }
```

And, in the IDM Audit.log, the error was like shown below:

```
WARN {AUDIT_LOG}-  Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Authentication Target=TESTDOMAIN/testuser Data=null Outcome=Failure  Error={"Error Message":"Un-expected error while pre-authenticating, Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION","Error Code":"31002"}
```

After 5 attempts of user login, the user is getting logged in successfully without any problem.
I'm not getting any clue and not understanding why this login failure happens randomly.

Please provide your solutions/ideas regarding this issue.

UPDATED:

After enabling user core debug logs and some other logs which seems to be relevant to this issue. During authentication failure, I could see following wso2carbon.log:

```
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager} -  Error occurred while checking existence of values.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 733,140 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 733,140 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
        ... 113 more
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Error occurred while validating grant
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 733,140 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 733,140 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the IS version you are using? have you enabled account locking on the users in primary or secondary user store?

Comment: Did you check the wso2carbon.log file of the WSO2 Identity Server for any errors?

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga Thanks for your comment. We're using pre-packaged Identity Server(wso2is-km-5.6.0) with API Manager(2.5.0) where Identity Server acts as a Key Manager. Yes, we have enabled account locking for both users in primary and secondary user store

Comment: @JayangaKaushalya Thanks for your comment. I am not seeing any errors in wso2carbon.log file of wso2is

Comment: This can occur when invoking a token request when the user account is locked. Enable User core debug logs (https://medium.com/nadees-tech-stories/enable-some-useful-debug-logs-on-wso2-products-usercore-ldap-connection-pooling-and-ssl-debug-b7fbedb6a5d).And let us know if there is any error. Seems like after user exceeds no of max attempts then when loading user claims it might create an exception. Also please let us know if this error also occur for PRIMARY user store users.

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga Actually, user account is not locked because if user account locked means I can see another error like this "{"error_description": "17003 Account is locked for user TESTDOMAIN/testuser. Cannot login until the account is unlocked."}" as response. Cannot able to open this (https://medium.com/nadees-tech-stories/enable-some-useful-debug-logs-on-wso2-products-usercore-ldap-connection-pooling-and-ssl-debug-b7fbedb6a5d)This link is showing 404 Page Not Found.
And this authentication failure I am seeing only for Secondary userstore users not for Primary user store users.

Comment: https://medium.com/nadees-tech-stories/enable-some-useful-debug-logs-on-wso2-products-usercore-ldap-connection-pooling-and-ssl-debug-b7fbedb6a5d . Use this link Enable User core debug logs and try the scenario

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga. Thank you! As per your suggestion, I followed the steps which were described in that link and I updated my question regarding enable user core debug logs.

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU, It seems like there is a connection issue between your database, Can you try to append 'autoReconnect=true' in the connection URL of the user store

Comment: @senthalan.Thanks. But, I already added 'autoReconnect=true' in the connection URL but still facing the same issue

Comment: It seems that mysql autoReconnect property does not work in the connection url of the User Stores -> Add (JDBCUserStoreManager). But if you configure this secondary user store manually in user-mgt.xml pointing at a datasource defined in master-datasources.xml with autoReconnect=true it works! But.....now when you try to access User Stores -> List from the carbon panel, you get this JSPException: JSPException while including path '/userstore_config/index.jsp' Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: I faced this problem when I enabled account locking , could you please help me to solve this problem : ERROR - Carbon Based Principal Database User not authenticated@BuddhimaUdaranga

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @senthalan in the comments, let's try adding "autoReconnect=true" to the end of the connection URL.

Additionally, please verify you are having the following recommended values under connection configurations for your MySQL datasources in the master-datasources.xml. (As described in [1])

```
<definition type="RDBMS">
   <configuration>
       <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/umdb?autoReconnect=true</url>
       <username>regadmin</username>
       <password>regadmin</password>
       <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
       <maxActive>80</maxActive>
       <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
       <minIdle>5</minIdle>
       <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
       <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
       <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
       <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
```

Also, we can increase the number of `max_connections` from the DB side as described in [2].

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections = 500;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+to+MySQL

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/19991390/2910841

Comment: I added 'autoReconnect=true' already and all the configurations what you have provided was also there in my userstore related .xml file. Similarly, we set `max_connections=1000` as default for our database. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Could you confirm you have added these configurations and "autoReconnect=true" to all the MySQL data sources?

Comment: FYI. I'm facing this issue only for the users under secondary user store database where I enabled all the configurations as you mentioned. Other than secondary user store database, for all other DBs also I enabled these configurations.